# Delete a record with Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, record, sql-delete

I am working with `MySQL`. I want to create a trigger who delete a record which has a value of 0 in the `Recette_verif` column. So I wrote this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Recette_verif` AFTER UPDATE ON `recette`
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM recette WHERE (Recette_verif = 0)
```

But, when I try to update `Recette_verif`, I get this error:

```
UPDATE `recette` SET `Recette_Statut` = '0' WHERE `recette`.`ID_Recette` = 1 AND _
`recette`.`ID_Ingredient_Recette` = 12
```

> 1442 - Can't update table 'recette' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I have tried a lot of things but it's not working.

Comment: Show what the "lots of things are" that you have tried. Otherwise how do we know what you have and haven't done?

Comment: Change the before and after, try DELETE, DROP, DELETE FROM

Comment: In MySQL, it is not possible to use a trigger to change a different row in the same table that the trigger is on. That is what your error message is telling you ("update" meaning a general change to the table, in your case it refers to the `delete`). This includes indirect changes, if you are e.g. thinking about tricking MySQL by using several trigger (trigger on table A changes table B which has a trigger that deletes the row in table A). To delete your row, you have to execute a seperate query outside of a trigger. Or it is a sign that your data model might need improvement.